# SQL Update with results of SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an extensive SQL SELECT That performs a calculation of TotalNetWorth for a number of Users. The result is the TotalNetworth and User. This can contain multiple records. Example:

```
-------------------------
|TotalNetWorth | UserId |
-------------------------
|  24.45       |  1     |
|  45.34       |  3     |
-------------------------
```

What I want to do is update the `NetWorth` column in my `Users` table with the `TotalNetWorth` value, and `UserId` = `Users.Id` as the key.  What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What database server? The answer can be different; SQL Server, for instance, has CTEs where MySQL doesn't.

Comment: @KenWhite didn't think it made a difference. I've updated with the mySQL tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` on an aliased subquery.

```
UPDATE 
  Users
FROM 
  Users u 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT WhatEver FROM YourQueryThatCalcsNetWorth) nw 
ON 
  nw.UserID = u.UserId
```

Comment: I test this and get error on `FROM Users U` section. Removing this section make query to work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
UPDATE u
FROM Users u 
JOIN tableTotalNetWorth t ON t.UserID = u.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempNetWorth AS (SELECT * FROM [your query])

UPDATE Users u, TempNetWorth t
SET u.NetWorth = t.TotalNetWorth
WHERE u.UserID = t.UserId
```

Comment: A temporary table isn't needed here. A simple join on an aliased subquery will work just fine. (Note that I'm not downvoting; just making a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

do your select first and then update immediately with `cte` help

```
WITH cte_query AS (
    SELECT TotalNetWorth = <calculate_total>
    FROM [Users])
UPDATE cte_query
SET TotalNetWorth = TotalNetWorth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do an `INSERT .... SELECT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ....`, as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use your extensive SELECT query to pull data into a temporary table first, say "temp" and then try using this query:

```
Update Users set NetWorth = (select TotalNetWorth from temp where Users.Id = temp.UserId)
```

Comment: No temp table needed. You can alias the subquery and do a direct `INNER JOIN`.